# Set a group's value based on a aggregation of all the records inside it in SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, group-by, reportbuilder

I have got this situation in report builder for SSRS where I would like to add a column for each Company with a Complete/Not complete label as follow:

If all the records for a CompanyId is "Complete" then the group's label (Company status) should state 'Complete', otherwise, if even one of the records has other labels than "Complete", then the group's label (Company status) should state "Not complete". How would you approach this in SSRS table/matrix design?

[image]

Comment: You 'd better solve in the SQL query by self joining the status table in order to get the min/max status per company and use it to group the rows. Seem's hard if possible to implement this inside SSRS

Comment: @niktrs  If anything, this is harder in the SQL query.  Performance will depend on the local environment and data, but this is definitely possible within the report.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a group on `companyid` you can just use some conditional aggregation on the value in the `Status` column:

```
=iif(sum(iif(Fields!Status.Value <> "Complete"
            ,1
            ,0
            )
        ) > 0
    ,"Not Complete"
    ,"Complete"
    )
```

Comment: You cannot use an aggregate in SSRS for grouping

Comment: @niktrs  You don't need to.  You group on the `companyid` and use the expression in my answer as the text box value.